# Sorting of the distance from the origin, the x and y coordinates using linked list in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

I am having some problems related to sorting linked list in c++. I have been given an assignment to finish and I have created the logic, but my linked list doesn't sort.

The program asks the user to input the name, x and y coordinates in order to calculate the Euclidean distance from the origin in the function called "auf2_euclidcalc". Then I'm using the function named "auf2_euclidcalc" inside the function "auf5_display()" to display the values of distances.

The program compiles and displays the inputs by the user perfectly, but doesn't sort the distance from the origin in ascending order (the function for sorting is "auf4_sort ()").

I need assistance regarding this in sorting the distance from the origin and the respective x and y coordinates. Could someone please help? Please correct errors in the sort function to make it sort.

Thanks in advance!
Please see my program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct thenode  //auf 1
{
string nameofobstacle;
double x, y;
double distancetotheorigin;
thenode *next;

};

thenode *head = nullptr;
thenode *last = nullptr ;


void insertobstacle (string nameofobstacle, double x, double y);
double auf2_euclidcalc (double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2);
void auf4_sort ();
void auf5_display();
void outputobstacles();
void auf6_pointstobedeleted ();

void insertobstacle (string nameofobstacle, double x, double y) 
{
thenode *storenewnode = new thenode;          //   newstorefourdata->distancetotheorigin = distancetotheorigin;

storenewnode->nameofobstacle = nameofobstacle;
storenewnode->x = x;
storenewnode->y = y;
storenewnode->next = head;
head = storenewnode;
double x2, y2;
x2 = storenewnode->x;
y2 = storenewnode->y;
auf2_euclidcalc(0, x2, 0, y2);
}


double auf2_euclidcalc (double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)   //Auf 2
{


thenode *ptr_storedx_y = new thenode;

double d;      //how to link this to the structure so that we can store x and y
double p1= x1-x2;
double p2= y1-y2;
ptr_storedx_y->distancetotheorigin= pow(p1, 2) + pow(p2, 2);
d= sqrt(ptr_storedx_y->distancetotheorigin); //obs.d

return d;

}


void auf5_display()
{
double d;
thenode *tempo=new thenode;
tempo=head;
while(tempo!=nullptr)
{
   double x1, y1, x2, y2;
   x1=0; //from origin
   y1=0; //from origin
   x2=tempo->x; //inputted dist
   y2=tempo->y; //inputted dist

  cout << "obstacle " << tempo->nameofobstacle << ": ( " <<setprecision(3) << tempo->x << " ,  " << 
  setprecision(3) <<tempo->y << " ) , ";
  tempo = tempo->next;



  cout<< "distance: " << auf2_euclidcalc(x1, x2, y1, y2) << endl;

}
}

void auf4_sort ()
{
double x_cor,y_cor;
string p_name;
double temproll;
thenode *temphead = head;

auf2_euclidcalc(0, x_cor, 0, y_cor);

int counter = 0;
while (temphead!=nullptr) //IT SHOULD CHANGE TO TEMP NULL
{
temphead = temphead->next;
counter++;
}
temphead = head;

for (int j=0; j<counter; j++)
{
while (temphead->next!=nullptr)  //iterate through list until next is null
{
if (temphead->distancetotheorigin > temphead->next->distancetotheorigin)
{

temproll = temphead->distancetotheorigin;
temphead->distancetotheorigin = temphead->next->distancetotheorigin;
temphead->next->distancetotheorigin = temproll;

             p_name = temphead->nameofobstacle;
             temphead->nameofobstacle = temphead->next->nameofobstacle;
             temphead->next->nameofobstacle = p_name;

             x_cor = temphead->x;
             temphead->x = temphead->next->x;
             temphead->next->x = x_cor;

             y_cor = temphead->y;
             temphead->y = temphead->next->y;
             temphead->next->y = y_cor;

             temphead = temphead->next;


}
else
temphead = temphead->next;//increment node

}
temphead = head;//reset temphead
}


}


void auf6_pointstobedeleted ()
{
   thenode *deletenow;
   while (head != nullptr)
   {
   deletenow = head;
   head = head->next;
   cout << "delete: " << deletenow->nameofobstacle << " :DELETED: " << endl;
   delete deletenow;
   }
}

int main ()
{

thenode *ptrstoring = new thenode;

while (cin)
{
cout<< "string describing obstacle ('end' for end of input): "<<endl;
cin>> ptrstoring->nameofobstacle;
if (ptrstoring->nameofobstacle=="end" || ptrstoring->nameofobstacle== "END")
{
    break;
}
else
{
    cout<< "x and y coordinate: " <<endl;
    cin>> ptrstoring->x;
    cin>> ptrstoring->y;
    insertobstacle (ptrstoring->nameofobstacle, ptrstoring->x, ptrstoring->y);


}




}


auf4_sort ();
auf5_display();
auf6_pointstobedeleted ();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your linked list class to see if it can sort something simple, like a linked list of integers?  If it can't do that, then there is no way it's going to be able to sort something more complex.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program one line at a time, what observations did you make? This is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your programs one line at a time, inspect all variables and their values as they change, and analyze your programs' logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find the bug in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I'm new to programming, started learning programming from the last semester with C and using C++ in the current semester. But for the time being only the sorting function does not seem to work, could you please provide me suggestions on that? Your help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Sam just gave you some of the best advice you will ever be given.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll try that out. The other functions that I called in the int main () functions seem to work correctly, the problem is in the sorting, could you kindly check that part out? Thanks in advance

Comment: `auf2_euclidcalc(0, x_cor, 0, y_cor);` uses `x_cor`, and `y_cor` before they have been given values.  This can cause all sorts of weird errors. Most modern compilers will warn you about problems like this. Don't ignore warnings. They are your first line of defense against bugs.

Comment: Suggestion: learn how to use your debugger. Use it to execute your sorting function, one line at a time, with a linked list that contains only two values. See how it works. If it doesn't this is simple enough of a test case for you to see the problem. If you don't, repeat with a three element linked list. And so on. Stackoverflow is not a web site where someone can find someone else to debug their programs for them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks once again. I'll learn to use debugger

Comment: A few hours spent now to learn the basics of debugging will save you hundreds of hours of frustration in the long run.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica I'll see it

Answer (score 1):

I don't scan the whole code but nevertheless I can make a few points.

Question that comes to mind why you create a new node in a **auf2_euclidcalc** function and doesn't use it later producing a memory leak.

Regarding your sorting algorithm. In a second loop you traverse the whole list over and over but after the run you know that the last element is either swapped or on the right place. So you can ignore it later in other iterations. Therefore list is being sorted from the tail.

Also, some implementations use boolean flags instead of counters. This flag is set when nodes violate their order and the algorithm works as long as there are swaps. Be aware that counting all nodes in a list is O(n).

For convenience you can create a swap function for your node struct.

```
void swap(thenode *lhs, thenode *rhs)
{
    swap(lhs->distancetotheorigin, rhs->distancetotheorigin);
    swap(lhs->nameofobstacle, rhs->nameofobstacle);
    swap(lhs->x, rhs->x);
    swap(lhs->y, rhs->y);
}
```

Ckeckout [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-bubble-sort-linked-list/) for more explanation on bubble sort in a linked list.

With no offense I want to say that you should make a habit to have a consistent expressive code style. Please, checkout C++ guidelines regarding this problem.